# GStreamer can't determine running time for this packet without knowing configured latency

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to forward an RTSP stream through WebRTC using GStreamer. I keep getting a massive amount of warnings about latency:

```
Can't determine running time for this packet without knowing configured latency
```

The pipeline is:

```
rtspsrc location=my_rtsp_url is-live=true ! 
queue ! 
decodebin ! 
videoconvert ! 
openh264enc ! 
video/x-h264,profile=constrained-baseline ! 
rtph264pay aggregate-mode=zero-latency ! 
webrtcbin turn-server=turn://test:test@localhost:3478 bundle-policy=max-bundle name=webrtcbin
```

I can't seem to figure out what I need to set to get rid of these messages. I tried looking through the source code for GStreamer. As best I can tell, the rtp session (gstrtpsession.c) is finding that send_latency is GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE.

Is there something I can add to my pipeline to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I think your problem here is that your application does not handle the GST_MESSAGE_LATENCY. You have to handle that and properly reconfigure the latency on the pipeline at that point, e.g. by calling gst_bin_recalculate_latency() on the pipeline. Once you do that, the problem should disappear."

This fixes the issue for me.

Credit to: @slomo from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/-/issues/1659